# How to map a Resource to an enum constant?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, dependency-injection, enums

I'm currently refactoring a (former) monster of a method in a Spring-MVC controller. The method basically does the following things:

1. Digs up a few identifiers from the request
2. Gets an XML representation for a product identified by them from a cache
3. Uses an XSL stylesheet to produce a PDF (which it then stores to a cache and adds the key it can be found with to the `Model`).

I've been able to remove almost all duplicated logic by making a `Product` enum which contains all the other product specific things, but the locations of the XSL stylesheets are problematic. Previously they were configured as `org.springframework.core.io.Resource`-type properties of the controller bean, but now that the product specific things are in the enum, I would either need to map them somehow to the enum constants or find another solution for locating them.

I think it would be best to have the XSL as part of the enum since there's a 1-to-1 relationship between them, but there's no way to inject the resource there. Using the class loader to load the resource to the enum manually would work in tests, but would be problematic in production environment since the stylesheet files are not in the classpath there. Plus I wouldn't like to make the enum depend on any Spring stuff.

Any ideas on how to tackle this problem without making the enum and the controller too tightly coupled?

Answer (score 0):

In the end I made the enum an inner class of the controller and added an abstract method called `getXsl` to it. The implementing enum constants now return the related `Resource` directly. I didn't have to change anything else since the `Resource` beans were already static.